# html + css table design change

Tags: html, css, css-tables

In the homepage of my website I would like to display 12 pictures, equally sized, in a 3 by 4 grid. I would like to avoid tables because in the CSS I've got 2 media queries that are "changing" the layout from 3 by 4 to 2 by 6 and to 1 by 12 when the screen is not big enough, but if there's a way to "change layout" with tables I'm totally ok with it. The issue I'm having is that when I'm displaying not 12, but 11 pictures, the last one is not centered.

The code of the first 3 divs is as follows (the other 9 are pretty much the same):

```
    .divThumb1{
    float: left;
    width: 31%;
    max-width: 288px;
    margin: 0%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.divThumb2{
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 31%;
    max-width: 288px;
    margin: 0%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.divThumb3{
    float: right;
    width: 31%;
    max-width: 288px;
    margin: 0%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Any suggestions? Please let me know if you need more infos!

Comment: Can you write your full code? I cant understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve such responsive layout, you may want to look into using the grid layout offered in a popular CSS framework named Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Once you included Bootstrap, using something like:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   <div class="col-md-4"></div>
   ...
</div>
```

should allow you achieve your purpose without customizing each div manually. Be sure to look into `.col-xs-`, `.col-sm-`, `.col-md-`, and `.col-lg-` as well. They are well documented.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a responsive image grid with a maximum width. All images are centered. I hope you find it useful!

```css
.imageGrid {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

.imageGrid * {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
}

.imageGrid > img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 31%;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageGrid">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" alt="img"/>
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" alt="img"/>
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" alt="img"/>
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" alt="img"/>
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" alt="img"/>
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" alt="img"/>
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" alt="img"/>
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" alt="img"/>
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" alt="img"/>
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" alt="img"/>
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" alt="img"/>
</div>
```